# Adding ellipses to different treatments in a PCA plot in R? (treatments are different columns)

Tags: r, pca

I'm rather new to R and have been trying to analyze some of my proteomic data with it. In particular, I'm trying to make a PCA plot so that I can see some of the similarities/differences between my different treatments. I essentially have 5 treatments, each in triplicates, so 15 columns total. My 95 rows are each represented by a different Protein ID. My actual data are normalized LFQ intensities, which is only to say that it's numeric and I know a PCA analysis/plot is appropriate.

I was able to successfully create a PCA plot with this code:

```
PlantPCA <- prcomp(Plant_Num_Named, center = TRUE, scale = TRUE)
summary(PlantPCA)

#create a quick plot
plot(PlantPCA$x[,1],PlantPCA$x[,2], xlab="PC1 (69.4%)", ylab = "PC2 (9.2%)", main = "PC1 / PC2 - plot")

#full plot
fviz_pca_ind(PlantPCA, geom.ind = "point", pointshape = 21, 
             pointsize = 2) +
  ggtitle("2D PCA-plot from 15 feature dataset") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

Which gives me this:
[My PCA Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wlgG.png)

I know it's basic I just wanted to get it to work first. However, now I want to add ellipses to surround my 5 different treatments, disregarding the different triplicates, and I'm not sure how to do so. I've seen people be able to do this when what they want to color by be another column of categorical data--but that isn't the case here.

Ideally, I would have 5 different colors for my treatments (which again are currently different columns) and the ellipses would match the color.

I want something similar to this:
[Example Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Ytxr.png)

From this tutorial website: https://towardsdatascience.com/principal-component-analysis-pca-101-using-r-361f4c53a9ff

Is this something that is attainable? I just need a little direction. Any and all advice is welcome!

Comment: A sample of your dataset (Plant_Num_Named) would help us better understand the problem (Using `dput()`). How do you distinguish between the different treatment groups in the dataset? Usually this is done by having a extra column with a group name or number for each observation, indicating which treatment/group it belongs to. You then color the observations by this group colum in the `fviz_pca_ind()` function and add the parameter `addEllipses = TRUE`. This is all present in the tutorial link you provided.

Comment: Here is a sample of the data:

Comment: `dput(Plant_Num_Named)
structure(c(22.6137, 20.7682, 20.152, 20.0936, 20.3734, 21.0062, 23.9733, 22.2437, 23.1885, 19.7636, 23.45, 20.3769, ...), .Dim = c(95L, 15L), .Dimnames = list(c("A0A1I9LR27;F4JBC9;Q9LU86", "A0A1P8ATL2;Q9SA52", "A0A1P8B2C7;F4IGR5;F4IGR4;P51407", ...), c("Control1", "Control2", "Control3", "PEIInfil1", "PEIInfil2", "PEIInfil3", ...)))`                       Here is a sample. Thanks for the response! I edited it down so that it would fit in this comment better. My protein IDs are the row names and different treatments are the column names.

Comment: The dput output must not be edited. You can edit your original question and add the data. Try `dput(head(Plant_Num_Named, n = 30))`. This will only output the first 30 rows, which we can use as a sample dataset. Add this to the top of your question.